# Finding optimal strategy of spending some supply if the demand is random

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

There is a sailor on a ship. He has food supply for 10 days. He enters a storm. He can only return to the port when the storm abates, so he has to evenly distribute his food for all days of storm. He knows storm days distribution, but he doesn't know in advance how long this particular storm will last.

What is the optimal strategy for him?

In other words, how he should split his 10 units of foods per day to make food distribution as even as possible?

I can guess that the optimal strategy should be to distribute food between days as per distribution of storm days. I.e. integrate storm days distribution, divide food supply by this number and thus get the coefficient to multiply by storm days distribution to get proper food distribution. But how can I prove it? Is it really correct?

Comment: Is the trivial solution (no food at any day) allowed?

Comment: No, trivial solution is not allowed.

Comment: Can you provide the optimal strategies assuming that every storm always takes equally long? Say, every storm takes 4 days. Should he then eat 10/4 food every day? Or will he eat at max 1 food per day? Is 10/4 food per day better than 1 food per day? Maybe it would be best to provide the cost function you try to minimize/maximize...

Comment: If he spends >1 unit of food per days its not an issue. We can admit that food quantity is 1 and we need to split it. The question is how he should do it. What he should do after 1st day, after 2nd day etc to have something on the last day.. Actually I see that the problem is not formed very well. I have only the idea of optimal strategy: the optimal strategy is the one where food is distributed as even as possible between the days for all possible storm day sequences.

Comment: Yes, I think your problem is not well posed, yet. Currently, if the #storm days is not upper bounded, the trivial solution is the only optimal one. If you don't allow it, there is no optional one. This is because you currently only look on "evenness" of food, not on amount. Thus, it would be optimal to eat 1/n food for all storms $\leq n$ days, but 1/(n+1) would even be better because it would be optimal for all storms $\leq n+1$ days, and 1/(n+2) would still be a bit better, and so on.

Comment: ok, guys, you are right. Let me try to rebuild it. Optimal solution is when ALL FOOD is evenly distributed between the days of the storm. I.e. if storm is 1 day - the sailor eats all food in 1 day. If storm is 10 days - he eats 1/10 of food each day. This solution is not reachable because we dont know the future. The goal is to find the strategy which gives the solution which is the closest to the optimal one. Does it make sense?

Comment: So, what you probably want is something like $argmax_P(E[min_t(P(t))])$, i.e. you want a strategy $P$, $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}P(t)=1$, which maximizes the expected minimal amount of food the sailor has to live with during the storm...

Comment: You will then find out that it never makes sense to eat more food than the day before, i.e. $P$ is monotone decreasing. If the storm ends on day $t$, the minimal food you ate is thus $P(t)$. Let $Q(t)$ be the probability that the storm ends at day $t$. Then, the average min food you eat is $\sum_tP(t)Q(t)$. You want to maximize this. Assume that also Q is monotone decreasing and take over from here